# Hosted bug tracking software

Tags: bug-tracking, bug-tracker

I'm looking for a free bug tracking software (hosted preferably, as my host doesn't allow me to use ssh, so i can't really install anything). What i want to do with it, is put a form on my website, and allow my beta testers to send in bugs (for now, only beta testers know of the site, so no login required).

I do have PHP and MySql, but all the software i came across needed SSH someplace during the installation. I tried Mantis, bugzilla and fogbugz.

I tried fogbugz, but i can't find any way to let users send in new bugs without logging in. Also, their XML api does not seem to allow you to add new bugs through it.

So what i basically need is:
-Bugtracking software
-Free
-Hosted
-Ability to send in bugs through either 
1. Interface on their host, without having to log in
2. Ability to embed, without having to log in 
3. Something like an XML Api, which allows me to send in new bugs

Does anyone know of one that can do these things, or have other tips?

Comment: *"hosted preferably, as my host doesn't allow me to use ssh, so i can't really install anything"*? Does your "host" allow to install PHP/mysql? You don't need ssh to do that.

Comment: I do have PHP and MySql, but all the ones i came across needed me to use SSH during the installation.

Comment: Have you tried **Bugzilla**? It looks very flexible, I think it must be configurable via ftp... Or you could try **Mantis** also.

Comment: Ok. I tried installing it on my server without SSH and i got quite far, however... Apparently i don't even have enough permissions on 0000free.com to set up the mysql database properly. Now i really need a hosted solution... untill we get a decent host.

Comment: Many web-hosting companies will do their best to allow you setup database etc. properly, so I don't see problem here.

Comment: There shouldn't. But the installation of Mantis says that it can't access enough. I'm currently trying to set it up manually or try something else... Is there a bugtracker that just uses a database already in place? Bugzilla aparently also needs SSH access (to run a Perl script).

Comment: yes, maybe you could try to install it on our own linux box and then just FTP transfer the php files, maybe manually edit some setup files...

Comment: Hmm, i can check if i can edit the setup files manually. The main thing i have to do, i believe, is set up the admin username etc. However, it also seems i can't really make an open web interface for users to report bugs, as the API doesn't seem to support adding bugs. Will look further into it. Currently also checking out Request Tracker, a rather simple bugtracking software, very open.

Comment: Ah, now i remember the problem. I have to enter my hostname, but apparently i don't seem to have access to that (asked on the forums of my hosting provider). No idea if i can use any SQL-based bugtracker at all then...

Comment: Hostname of what? Of the sql database? Then use exactly the same setup as you normally use when you connect the database from PHP.

Comment: Ok, somehow it does work now. I edited the config file manually, with the same details i entered in the wizard, but when i ran the wizard again after that it did work. Thanks for the help! If you post an answer with the things you said i will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: OK, done. I'm glad it helped! Sometimes you need to hack things a little to make it work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have normal hosting with just PHP/MySQL and FTP access, you could try to install the bug tracking software on our own linux box and then just FTP transfer the php files, maybe after you manually edit some setup files. You will also need to specify the connection to the database, but then use exactly the same setup as you normally use when you connect the database from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at OnTime11 from [axosoft](http://www.axosoft.com/). It's hosted, free for 2 users and looks extremely polished with a great feature set. There's a slick 2 min demo link on the homepage.

Comment: *"Save Big Until Sept 30th!", "Sign Up for a Demo.", "get a $100-off coupon code." ...* doesn't look like free solution...

Comment: @Tomas - I signed up to it - it's completely free.

Comment: That's what Erik asked for - to use something for himself.

Comment: I don't think so: *"...and allow my beta testers to send in bugs ..."*